# Search mySQL table for user and return true or false to $result?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

What I've been trying to do for several hours now is simply check the column 'user' of a table 'nonpersonal' to match my variable '$recipient'.

I thought there must be a much easier way than selecting the whole column 'user', putting it through a while loop with fetch_assoc() and only then check if there is a 'user' that matches '$recipient'.

If yes, please tell me! :) If not, what would be the most efficient way? I tried in_array(), e.g., but couldn't get it to work. I guess I'm missing the basic understanding of how the query($sql) fills $result, which I tried to find out as well..

```
    $sql = "SELECT user FROM nonpersonal WHERE user LIKE '$recipient'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if($recipient == $result)) {        
        echo "<br> This recipient does exist."
    } else {
        echo "<br> This recipient does not exist. Try again.<br>";
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an exact query... LIKE is for partial or inexact matches.

```
$sql = "SELECT user FROM nonpersonal WHERE user = '$recipient'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
  echo 'Exists!';
}
```

Also please be sure you have escaped `$recipient` to ensure you do not allow SQL injection, see [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I know this is a very basic question, but what does the '->num_rows' part do? Does it check for the number of rows that were SELECTed by the query($sql)?

And concerning the escaping: Isn't it sufficient to put the $variable in ' '?

It works nicely btw. Thank you very much. Geoffrey. :))

Comment: @anarchist912 Correct, it returns the number of records returned.

Comment: And concerning the escaping: Isn't it sufficient to put the $variable in ' '?

Comment: @anarchist912 Certainly not! Think about this... what if `$recipient` contains a single quote... your SQL will become: `SELECT user FROM nonpersonal WHERE user = 'O'Conner'`, let alone some malicious SQL such as `' or '' = '` which would become `SELECT user FROM nonpersonal WHERE user = '' or '' = ''`